# Highcharts with JSON data and multiple series

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm trying to render a Highcharts line chart, but am having some issues getting the series to show up when the page loads.  Firebug doesn't show any errors, so I'm guessing that it's a problem with how my data is structured or how it is being passed to Highcharts.

The data comes from a JSON file, with the variables being loaded using a method I got from [another site](http://jonathanmanning.com/2012/10/31/highcharts-jquery-graphing-library-example-with-json-data-source/)...  My data is a numeric y value for each month, with customTooltip being additional data I want to show on hover.

```
$.getJSON("json/mydata.txt",function(jdata) {

var arr = [];
$.each(jdata, function(key, val) {
    var y = val.y;
    var name = key;
    var customTooltip = val.n;
    arr.push({y: y, customTooltip: customTooltip})
})

var jseries = {name:arr.name, data:[{ny:arr.customTooltip, y:arr.y}]};

var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'fallcontainer',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Rate',
                style: {
                    margin: '10px 100px 0 0' // center it
                }
                },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source',
                style: {
                    margin: '0 100px 0 0' // center it
                }
                },
            xAxis: {

                categories: ['Jan 12', 'Feb 12', 'Mar 12']
                },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Rate',
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }],
                min:0
                },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align:'right',
                verticalAlign:'middle',
                x:0,
                title:'Care Setting'
                },
            plotOptions: {
                },
            credits: {
                enabled:false
                },
            series:[]
};

options.series.push(jseries);

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Here's a better example.  What I really want to display is the 'y' as the y-axis with the 'n' and 'y' data on the hover.  JSONLint said this is valid.

```
{
"Total": {
    "y": [
        9.39,
        90.35,
        90.36,
        92.69,
        93.02,
        90.32,
        90.6,
        9.09,
        9.5,
        90.69,
        9.6,
        90.69,
        9.53,
        6.92
    ],
    "name": "Total",
    "n": [
        962,
        969,
        999,
        233,
        235,
        968,
        999,
        963,
        989,
        293,
        986,
        293,
        989,
        908
    ]
},
"Cat1": {
    "y": [
        6.38,
        6.63,
        90.3,
        9.65,
        90.25,
        8.99,
        92.39,
        99.39,
        9.28,
        99.35,
        99.36,
        93.38,
        8.69,
        8.03
    ],
    "name": "Cat1",
    "n": [
        6,
        6,
        90,
        90,
        90,
        8,
        93,
        93,
        99,
        93,
        93,
        96,
        99,
        9
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show example of your data? Are you sure that is that JSON? Use some online validators (copy there your data) and make sure you have proper JSON.

Comment: I added an example of the data to the OP.  What I really want to display is the 'y' as the y-axis with the 'n' and 'y' data on the hover.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look at this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

If you specify each point as an object, you can add any property you want to each point and access it in your tooltip formatter through this.point.

With the data as currently formatted

```
var seriesArr = [];
$.each(jdata, function(key, data) {
  var series = {name : key, data : []};

  $.each(data.y, function(index, value) {
    series.data.push({y: value });
  });

  $.each(data.n, function(index, value) {
    series.data[index].n = value;
  });
  seriesArr.push(series);
});
```

This should yield :

```
seriesArr : [{
    name : 'Total',
    data : [
      {y:9.39, n:9.62},
      ...
    ]
  },
...
]
```

Then in your formatter function, you can acccess each as this.point.y or this.point.n

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function () {
    return 'Y value is : ' + this.point.y + '<br>' + 'N value is : ' + this.point.n;
  }
},
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/sgearhart2/9P5fC/

Comment: Thanks a ton, that fixed it.  I can see that my data is now an object in firebug.  The entries in the API reference are a lot clearer to me now as well, so this will be a great start.